# Glitch in full video on Reddit

Tags: video, fullscreen

Here I replicate a question I made on Reddit.
If anyone could help me...

> Hello,
>
> There is a glitch when I watching a full video on Netflix in my GF's notebook, I'd like to know if you guys know anything about. The browser is Firefox.
>
> Around 28 seconds into the video, you should see the video blink, and shows the screen below, in this case the icons from the Desktop, but it blinks whatever windows is below the current.
>
> Video card is Intel HD Integrated.

The video can be seen [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/eyywvx/glitch_on_full_video/).

Much appreciated.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try **ElectronPlayer**

Supports Netflix, Youtube, Twitch, Floatplane, Hulu, Amazon Prime Video And More.
This is the successor to Netflix-Desktop

You can install ElectronPlayer from snap.
This is recommended method of installation as automatic updates will occur.

You can install it by typing to the terminal:

```
sudo apt  update
sudo apt  install snap
sudo snap install electronplayer
```

Source:
https://github.com/oscartbeaumont/ElectronPlayer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, though I'm trying to figure out the problem.

Will look into the software to test.